# Laravel : Model saved with autogenerated uuid but instance of this model have this uuid empty

Tags: laravel, model, persistence, laravel-5.1

I use a trait for generate `uuid` on my model. It's work because, in my database the `uuid` value is not empty. But the current instance of my model don't have the new value.

this is the trait :

```php
trait UuidModel
{
    public static function bootUuidModel()
    {
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            // Don't let people provide their own UUIDs, we will generate a proper one.
            $model->uuid = Uuid::generate(4);
            return true;
        });

        static::saving(function ($model) {
            // What's that, trying to change the UUID huh?  Nope, not gonna happen.
            $original_uuid = $model->getOriginal('uuid');

            if ($original_uuid !== $model->uuid) {
                $model->uuid = $original_uuid;
            }
            return true;
        });
    }

    public function scopeUuid($query, $uuid, $first = true)
    {
        if (!is_string($uuid) || (preg_match('/^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-4[0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$/', $uuid) !== 1)) {
            throw (new ModelNotFoundException)->setModel(get_class($this));
        }

        $search = $query->where('uuid', $uuid);

        return $first ? $search->firstOrFail() : $search;
    }

    public function scopeIdOrUuId($query, $id_or_uuid, $first = true)
    {
        if (!is_string($id_or_uuid) && !is_numeric($id_or_uuid)) {
            throw (new ModelNotFoundException)->setModel(get_class($this));
        }

        if (preg_match('/^([0-9]+|[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-4[0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12})$/', $id_or_uuid) !== 1) {
            throw (new ModelNotFoundException)->setModel(get_class($this));
        }

        $search = $query->where(function ($query) use ($id_or_uuid) {
            $query->where('id', $id_or_uuid)
                ->orWhere('uuid', $id_or_uuid);
        });

        return $first ? $search->firstOrFail() : $search;
    }
}
```

This is my model :

```php
class Image extends BaseModel
{
    use UuidModel;

    protected $table = 'images';
    public $incrementing = false;
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $guarded = array('id', 'timestamps', 'path');
    protected $visible = array('timestamps', 'uuid');
    protected $hidden = array('id', 'path');

    public function Item()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Item', 'id', 'item_id');
    }

}
```

This is my Controller :

```php
class ImageController extends Controller
{
    ...

    public function store(CreateImageRequest $request, $itemSlug)
    {
        $item = $this->getItem($itemSlug);

        $image = new Image();
        $image->path = "";

        $image = $item->Images()->save($image);

        return Response::json($image->uuid, 201);
    }

    ...

}
```

And the response is always : `{}` but the uuid is not empty in my database.

**UPDATE**

This test works :

```php
public function store(CreateImageRequest $request, $collectionSlug, $itemSlug)
{
    $item = $this->getParentItem($collectionSlug, $itemSlug);

    $image = new Image();
    $image->path = $filePath;

    $image = $item->Images()->save($image);
    $newImage = Image::find($image->id);

    return Response::json($newImage->uuid, 201);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm having the same problem yesterday, here's the working trait

```
trait UuidTrait
{

  public static function bootUuidTrait(){
    static::creating(function($model){
      $model->incrementing = false;
      $model->{$model->getKeyName()} = Uuid::generate()->string;
    });
  }

}
```

so maybe here's the answer on your problem

```
static::creating(function ($model) {
        // Don't let people provide their own UUIDs, we will generate a proper one.
        $model->uuid = Uuid::generate(4)->string;
        return true;
});
```

i hope i would help someone :D

Answer (score 0):

You are hooking onto "creating" and "saving" events, but what you should be doing is hooking onto "creating" and "updating" events.

If you check [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#events) it says that "saving" event is triggered on both creating a new model and updating an existing one - so in your case it gets called when creating new model and thus leaves "uuid" value on previous one (which is nothing); and also when updating it's the same thing.

If you switch to "creating" and "updating" events then everything will work as you want it to - basically just replace "saving" with "updating" and that's it.